# Code working via editor but not when opening spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I want to open a specific sheet in one spreadsheet depending on the value in another spreadsheet. And it works very good when run directly from script editor but it doesn't work when opening the spreadsheet. Any ideas?

```
function onOpen() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("the_key").getSheetByName("Arkusz2").getRange("A5").getValue();
  app.setActiveSheet(app.getSheetByName(sheet));  
}
```

There is no error. Just nothing happens.

Comment: You need to use installable triggers. Rename your function and edit>Triggers>create new

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to have the code every time the first spreadsheet is opened; what you need to do is create an "on open" installable trigger. You can do this by:

- Going to the code editor, clicking on the clock button that is between the "save" and "run" ones.
- This will take you to the trigger site, on the bottom right corner there will be a "add new trigger" button.
- Click it and you can select triggers that best suit you.
- For the one you want, in "event source" select "From spreadsheet"
- On the "Event Type" Select "On Open".
- Save the trigger and it will be set.

[image: Trigger Button]

---

[image: Settings for your desired trigger]

Additionally, here is some documentation on triggers, in case you have any further question.
URL: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Alberto - it works. But why I don't need this installable trigger in another spreadsheet. Like in the code below. It works just as it is.

```
 function onOpen() {
      var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var arkusz = app.getSheetByName("Arkusz2").getRange("A2").getValue();
      app.setActiveSheet(app.getSheetByName(arkusz));
    }
```

Comment: In this code you're putting the value of the A2 cell in the Arkusz2 sheet of the current spreadsheet as the name of the sheet you want to open. This would act when you ran it and the spreadsheet is open, I believe it  would work from, say, an add-on, but I don't think you'll get it to just change the sheet from the editor.